# Can I get menu items or keyboard short cuts from the app that's in focus on OSX?

Tags: macos

I was thinking it would be cool if I could write a little OS X app that would look at the current app that's in focus and display all the available keyboard short cuts for that app in a small window so if you are working in a new program and you want to at a glance see what's available, that would be helpful for learning the commands.

My question is, does OS X provide a way for you to inspect menu items and look for keyboard short cuts within the app that is "in focus"?

Anyone's thoughts on how to accomplish this or if it's even worth exploring are much appreciated.

Comment: A product that does that already exists. See http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd like to try and build something like this as well. Where would I start in the Apple Documentation to figure this out?

Comment: I think the accessibility API provides the required functionality. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html